# Proving and understanding a limit

Tags: limits

I want to prove a certain limit.

Let $L_n, v_n$ be sequences, such that
$$L_n \to 0 \, , \quad v_n \to \infty \, , \quad v_nL_n \to \frac{\hbar^2\kappa}{2m}>0 \,,$$
where $\hbar, m, \kappa$ are constants.

What I want to show is the following:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{k^2+i\frac{2mv_n}{\hbar^2}}\cdot L_n \quad \to \quad 0\\
\end{align*}
(here $k$ is also a constant, but a complex number.)
My idea was to bound the squareroot with respect to $L_n$. I tried the following:
\begin{align*}
\left| k^2+i\frac{2mv_n}{\hbar^2}\right| &\leq \left| k^2+i\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\cdot\frac{C}{L_n} \right| \qquad \text{for $n$ large enough and $C$ a constant}\\
&\leq \frac{\tilde{C}}{L_n}\, ,
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{C}=k^2+\frac{2m\cdot C}{\hbar^2} (?)$.

Hence
$$\left|\sqrt{k^2+i\frac{2mv_n}{\hbar^2}}\right|  \leq \left| \frac{\sqrt{\tilde{C}}}{\sqrt{L_n}}\right| .$$
Now we see
\begin{align*}
\left|\sqrt{k^2+i\frac{2mv_n}{\hbar^2}}\cdot L_n\right|\leq \left| \frac{\sqrt{\tilde{C}}}{\sqrt{L_n}}\cdot L_n\right| = \left| \tilde{C}\cdot \sqrt{L_n}\right| \to 0
\end{align*}

Does this work? Or is there an  easier way to do this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think that you can indeed bound it by a multiple of $\sqrt{L_n}$ (I got it bounded by a multiple of $|v_n|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$) but I haven't got my head round the details of your estimate.